# What 68-pin connector is this on my 2.5" solid state drive?

Tags: ssd, connector, nvme

I have a Samsung PM983 2.5" SSD drive but I have never seen a connector like this.

Would like to use it but unsure of what I need to connect.

Can anyone assist?

[image: 2.5 inch SSD]

Comment: @Criggie, [yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR31e.png).

Comment: @BrockAdams that image is worthy of being in an answer.

Comment: @Criggie, go for it if you want.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's a U.2 interface, formerly known as SFF-8639.

U.2 can be used for SATA Express, SAS, or Enterprise PCIe.  As far as I can see, the 2.5" U.2 version of the Samsung PM983 is only available as PCIe.  In this case, it'd be possible to adapt to M.2 (NVMe only) or a PCIe x4 card.

Comment: I believe you meant to say "should". I've tried to look around, and there doesn't seem to be any *reliable* information about converting from U.2 to M.2 (but there's lots to go from M.2 to U.2).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel SU doesn't do shopping recommendations, but [they do exist](https://www.amazon.com/CableCreation-SFF-8639-SFF-8643-Compatible-Mainboard/dp/B07D8RBY7C/).

Comment: :/ my google-fu must be rusty. But that is an interesting find.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel EDIT: Was gonna say I will PM you the card I recommend but forgot you can't PM on here...I had much better luck getting a card that converted it directly to PCIe instead of that cable + adapter combo. Unfortunately, all the companies you will come across are pretty obscure/slightly shady.

Comment: @ScottSimontis I was actually looking for examples to compliment the answer, not to buy for myself. I can't afford that type of tech :(

Answer (score 17):

Per this table on the Samsung website, all PM983 drives use the PCIe Gen3 x4 interface which I believe is a data centre blade interface. I don't believe you can plug this into a desktop PC with a regular SATA style cable.

[image]

Comment: Correct, essentially a M.2 NVME conector in a different form-factor. Samsung also makes these same drives in the regular M.2 form-factor.

Comment: Is this also called U.2?

Comment: @EddieDunn Yes it is. https://rog.asus.com/articles/hands-on/easy-guide-to-ssds-sata-msata-m-2-and-u-2/

Comment: It’s strange that this Samsung table is so useless, the formfactor does not specify the m.2 size/height and the interface column does not mention u.2

Answer (score 1):

SAS (serial attached SCSI) in a form factor partially compatible with SATA

(SFF-8482)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI

p.s. it is partially compatible w/ SATA in a sense that a SAS host can run a SATA disk, but not the other way round.

Comment: This is not correct.  While mechanically compatible with the SAS connector, this a PCIe U.2 connector, as the other answers mention.

Comment: mea culpa. Didn't look at few more pins.